# Asignacion de variables no efectiva en metodo de Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Tengo una aplicacion, y estoy intentando recuperar una lista de productos desde cloud firestore.
El codigo:

```
    private var foodPetitions2: MutableList<FoodPetition> = mutableListOf()
    private var adapter = FoodAdapter2(foodPetitions2, this)
    private var db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_products)
        val bundle = intent.extras

        val docs = db.collection("productos").whereEqualTo("category", bundle?.get("category"))
        docs.get().addOnSuccessListener {
            for (document in it){
               addItem(FoodPetition(document.data["name"] as String, document.data["image"] as String, document.data["id"] as String))
            }
            addItem(FoodPetition("s", "a", "asdas"))
        }
        foodPetitions2.forEach{
            println(it.name)
            println(it.image)
            println(it.id)
        }

        setup()
    }
```

El problema es que los cambios a variables que hago dentro del addOnSuccessListener no se guardan, y no entiendo por que.

Comment: Que cambios estas haciendo dentro del addOnSuccessListener que no ves reflejados ? Podrias mostrarnos el metodo addItem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los cambios sí se se guardan, sólo que no instantaneamente. Cómo el nombre de la función indica, `OnSuccessListener` se ejecuta cuando la consulta se completa exitosamente. En tu código estás imprimiendo la lista inmediatamente después de hacer la consulta, por lo tanto no va a imprimir nada porque no hay manera de que tu consulta se complete antes de ese punto. Si necesitas usar el resultado de la consulta, debes hacerlo dentro del callback o también puedes usar la función [await](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/com.google.android.gms.tasks.-task/await.html) para esperar que la consulta termine.